# How to add Job Description into Jenkins email notification content

Tags: email, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

Using the *Configure System > Extended E-mail Notification* configuration in Jenkins I would like to add the description of my job (present on http://my-jenkins.org/job/myjob page) into the Default Content of build failure emails.

Is there any $PROJECT_DESCRIPTION variable that I can use for that ?
Or is it possible to do that using a Jelly/Groovy script ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by Zloj , Jenkins don't have such variable but you can customize your own. Jenkins have plugin to set Environment variables through a file by
[Envfile](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin) Plugin

Extract Description

```
grep -o '<description>.*</description>' /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/your_job_here/config.xml | sed 's/\(<description>\|<\/description>\)//g'
```

And save it in a file for eg: /tmp/ENV

If the content of description is "Hello world".

```
cat /tmp/ENV
$PROJECT_DESCRIPTION=Hello World
```

Now add $PROJECT_DESCRIPTION in your e-mail

For Dynamically updated description I have a workaround for you until I find a better solution...
create a shell script "wrapper.sh"

cat wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "PROJECT_DESCRIPTION=`grep -o '<description>.*</description>' /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/your_job_here/config.xml | sed 's/\(<description>\|<\/description>\)//g'`" > /tmp/env
```

This script creates your env file Dynamically.

Now Install [ManagedScript](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin) Plugin:-

Create a managed script file by following the above link with following content

```
sh /tmp/wrapper.sh
```

Now go to your project configuration:-

1). Under Build option add "Execute managed script and select the one you created in previous step

2). apply and save.

Voila.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Comment: As I understand it would work if content of job description never changes but in my case this description is dynamically updated with an URL (that may change in the future). And I do that using Jenkins REST API (POST to [http://myjenkins.org/job/myjob/config.xml](http://myjenkins.org/job/myjob/config.xml)) so I don't have any way to remotely modify the env variable value.

Comment: Do you think that it's possible to get content of Job Description from into a Jelly or Groovy script ?

Comment: Adev,  please check the edit.
Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such environmental variable, but you can set it yourself:

```
${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/config.xml
```

as one of the first entries contains an xml tag called 'description'. Parse it to a variable and then use to add to e-mail body via e-mail ext.