# Get POM parameters in Jenkins as a variable

Tags: jenkins, pom.xml

I have the use the POM parameters in Jenkins to send them as parameters to other JOBS. How can i dynamically read the POM variables as environment variables and send them as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EnvFile](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin) Plugin.

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569138/how-to-add-job-description-into-jenkins-email-notification-content/32602818#32602818) for how to export environment variables and pass as parameter

Edit:

Try [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Plugin, where you can dynamically change parameters according to the requirements.

Comment: i need to dynamically read the pom file content, as the pom file will change  many times. in that case i dont think this EnvFile plugin will work for this.